# Pushing all elements of a python list one element earlier

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I'm currently making a simple snake style game that moves through a 2 dimensional list(/array)
I also have a list holding the co-ordinates of each section of the snake. It's *mostly* working, except that the first and second elements of the array are always the same and I'm not sure why.

The way I do it is by iterating through the list backwards and taking the values from the previous element to apply to the current one.

ie. The last element in the list gets set to the values of the second last. Then the second last is set to the third last etc.

Here's the code:

```
while i < playerLength:
    x = playerSections[-i-1][0]
    y = playerSections[-i-1][1]
    playerSections[-i] = [x,y]
    i+=1
```

I know some simple work arounds to avoid this problem (eg. make the loop terminate one iteration sooner) but I'd like to know why this isn't working so I understand it better if anyone else can spot the bug.

Comment: Python indexing works based on first (inclusive) to last(exclusive) i.e. when you select a[1:4] it gives you a[1] a[2] and a[3].....if that makes sense

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the last element? You can always insert a new element at the start..

Comment: ...that would be much simpler!
I've been using too much Java, I forgot how flexible lists can be in other languages so this will cut down the initially intended code.

Comment: I swear ever single person that has coded snake (for learning purposes) has run into this question and invariably come to martjin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply delete the last element and add one to the front, like this:

```
l = [[1,1],[2,1],[2,2]]
l.pop[-1]
l.insert(0, [0,1])
```

this will remove the last element and insert a new one in front -- indices will be adapted.

The other way round (removing first element and adding to end) works like this:

```
l.pop[0]
l.append([2,3])
```

### Alternative:

I just came across [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque), which gives you a linked, double-ended list with dedicated functions to add or remove elements on either side. Might be faster as long as you're not performing operations on the intermediate elements, which should be given in your case.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: If efficiency is a concern (and a little more code complexity is okay), you'd use `array`, keep player length as a variable, and delete elements in batches (similar to garbage collection). That said, I agree that `deque` is a nice compromise: it avoids O(n) delete, but keeps the code simple.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn Pieters made a good point. Rather than moving the entire length of the snake in your array, you can just remove the last part of your snake and move it to the front.